# MySQL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP updates timestamp field in all rows?

Tags: mysql

It seems I cannot see the issue myself.

```
**my_table**
id
title
last_update (NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Query in PHP:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET 
    title='t4'
   WHERE
    id=3
```

Update is done specific to id, but for some reason *last_update* field is updated in ***all rows*** to the last records time. For example:

```
id  title last_update
1   t1    2018-08-02 03:37pm
2   t2    2018-08-02 03:37pm
3   t4    2018-08-02 03:37pm
```

NOTES: no triggers, functions or anything apart plain mysql query. I have tested it recently and still it is the same effect.

I wonder what can be even theoretical reason for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: That sounds rather impossible. Not even rather, more absolutely. Sure you are firing only this one single UPDATE query to begin with …?

Comment: Can you check the default value of `last_update` in table structure

Comment: It is highly impossible. I have tried it myself. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3d639/1

Comment: @Sinto - default: NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Is there any trigger or something to update that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly there was a php **date** function which had *mislabeled variable* from mysql... Many thanks for reassurances and suggested directions.